# jquery submit form with $_POST array to parent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

i use colorbox jquery plugin with iframe on a related product link as i dont want people to leave the current product page but i still want a link to the related product, hence:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

opens yet another product page that detects that it is opened in a frame:

```
if(window.parent.frames.length > 0) { ...some css changes here...
```

the only clickable item in that frame is an Add to Cart button which adds the related product to cart. for this to happen the form submits to PHP_SELF. means that page has to reload with the $_POST array. This works fine, but on click i'd like to close that frame, and reload the parent.

```
    $('#addtocartbutton').click(function() {
    document.cart_quantity.submit(); //this would reload page (in frame)
    parent.$.colorbox.close(); //closing frame stops the submit/reload
    parent.window.location.reload(true); //parent reloads but nothing added to cart 

});
```

this submits the form, closes the frame, and reloads the parent - but the submit did not have enough time to actually "add to cart". is there a way i can send the $_POST data to the parent, close the frame, and reload the parent page with that extra data?

Comment: post the data using ajax and reload the parent on success - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It can look like this

```
$('#addtocartbutton').click(function() {
    var p = parent;
    document.cart_quantity.submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: data,
           success: function(data){
                p.$.colorbox.close(); //closing frame stops the submit/reload
                p.window.location.reload(true); //parent reloads but nothing added to cart 
           }
         });
    }); //this would reload page (in frame)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me. i modified the form itself in the iframe:
`$("form[name='cart_quantity']").prop('target','_top').prop('action',parent.window.location.href+'?action=add_product');`

as any product page also includes the add-to-cart logic, changing the action to the parent page (or parent product) with additional target resulted in:
1) sending $_POST array without ajax
2) refreshing the parent page (now showing items in cart)
3) the refresh of course also removes the colorbox

hope this will help someone else one day.